# new ArrayList<>().add() NPE

Tags: java, spring, jpa

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Builder
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Long depth;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    private Category parent;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id")
    private Store store;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Category> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addChild(Category child) {
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

Cannot invoke "java.util.List.add(Object)" because "this.children" is null

when I try `parentCategory.addChild(childCategory)`

I initialized it with an empty list, but why does it happen?

Is the empty list null?

I want to know the correct way to initialize.

Comment: Run it with a debugger and see what it gets in the constructor. You're defining an "AllArgsConstructor" so whoever uses that gets to overwrite the value you set to "children" in the default constructor. This is the evil of Lombok: it gives you hidden code that works in the background without you even realizing it. In my opinion, you shouldn't be using Lombok for any business logic. Logging and toString methods are fine, but leave it there and you will shoot your own foot way fewer times. If you need to generate boilerplate code, use the code generation features of your IDE.

Comment: But if you're adamant on keeping the AllArgsConstructor annotation, you should put a NonNull annotation on the children-field. Then Lombok will add a null-checkt to it.

Comment: If the object you're trying to call your addChild-method on is retrieved from the db has null in the children-field, I believe that will replace your initialization. You might need to initialize the field in the add child-method, i.e. something like: `public void addChild(Category child) {if (child == null) {child = new ArrayList<>();} children.add(child);}`

Comment: If the `category` instance is returned by any hibernate query, the `children` collection is never null (even if no child is found in database) .Usually we set `children = new ArrayList<>()` only to make sure that when we do intently `new Category()`, the collection is not null.

Comment: Thanks for asking this, it was tricky to find the correct keywords, but finally on 10th attempt this question came up :) Suffering from the same issue at the moment and thinking of the right way to solve it

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're using the Builder to construct an instance of Category.  In doing this, the builder is overriding the children collection with null because you aren't passing it in the builder chain.

e.g.

```
Category.builder().build(); // will return an instance of Category with null children collection

new Category(); // will return an instance of Category with children set to an empty ArrayList.
```

Comment: I'm currently facing this issue in the unit test and it is as simple as creating an instance with `new`, then trying to access such "empty list" field which is failing with NullPointerException, so I'm scratching my head right now and found out that I'm not alone at least :)

Comment: Nah, debugging showed that you are 100% right, I just misread the unit test results: the one where constructor is called failed with NPE at different line :D but the other one used builder and the field was null exactly as described in your answer. Those legacy unit tests are a complete disaster D: